# How define boxes to avoid parenthesis

Tags: formatting, boxes

The following definition for boxes in `TraditionalForm` formats as $\{a,b\}\{c,d\}$ (for simplicty, it matches only if the arguments literally are `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`):

```
f /: MakeBoxes[f[a, b, c, d], TraditionalForm] := 
   RowBox[{RowBox[{"{", "a", "b", "}"}], RowBox[{"{", "c", "d", "}"}]}]:
```

Here is an example:

```
f[a, b, c, d] // TraditionalForm
```

> $\{a,b\}\{c,d\}$

However, when this object is multiplied by something, I get an unwanted parenthesis:

```
2*f[a, b, c, d] // TraditionalForm
```

> $2\,(\{a,b\}\{c,d\})$

How do I modify the box definition above to avoid the parenthesis?

Comment: maybe  `ClearAll[f];
f /: MakeBoxes[f[a, b, c, d], TraditionalForm] := RowBox[{"{", "a", "b", "}", "{", "c", "d", "}"}]`?
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [`InterpretationBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpretationBox), [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagBox) or [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) with a [`SyntaxForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxForm) option. For example:

```
MakeBoxes[f[a, b, c, d], TraditionalForm] ^:= InterpretationBox[
    RowBox[{RowBox[{"{","a","b","}"}], RowBox[{"{","c","d","}"}]}],
    f[a,b,c,d],
    SyntaxForm->"^"
]
```

Then:

```
2 f[a,b,c,d] //TraditionalForm
```

> 2 {a b}{c d}